# Android - Dynamic Resizing of Bottom Sheets

Tags: android, resize, bottom-sheet

I'm using the support libraries bottom sheets to show the user a dynamically changing TextView.

The problem is, when I change the BottomSheet's state to EXPANDED, it's size wont adapt to a different size of TextView

A video example of what I mean can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpJmDx2g53U&feature=youtu.be

What could i do to remedy this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the bottom sheet view to the required height in layout definition. Instead of making bottom sheet increase in height with content, you can use NestedScrollView so that bottom sheet height stays same but user can view the content by scrolling.